# Some links with accented characters and dot doesn't open on Chrome, Explorer and Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, xslt

I'm dealing with an issue at my work that I had never seen. When I'm developing I use always Firefox and generating an HTML by a XSL on JAVA I tested the links on Firefox and ALL works, even if they have or not accented characters or dots at the end of the URL (https://..........some words**.**) When you click on the link it sends you to the bottom of the page where is the info of that link (https://...............#name displayed on the clicked link

But today, my boss openned an issue telling me that on Chrome, Edge and Explorer, the links with accented characters or dots on the URL can't be openned. So I tried click some links and on Chrome, some works and others not work..... On Explorer and Edge none works. I'm very rookie dealing with display browser problems.

So, I've checked the code that transforms the XML template to HTML and I tried to add this two lines:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "text/html");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

(With these two lines, the browser shows a ? instead the accented characters, I don't know why)

Moreover, on the XML template I've added:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> </meta>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> </meta>
            </head>
...... more template code ......
```

But the result it's the same. On Firefox all links work, on Chrome some yes and some no, on Explorer and Edge none of them.

Why it works on Firefox and on the rest of all no?

Regards.

------------- UPDATE -------------

The file it's generated by a desktop application and creates a html file that it's opened at the end of the process by the default browser of the system.

I thought that the problem was not encoding on UTF-8, but I've changed the encondig to the original (ISO-8859-1) because the result it's the same.

The code is:

```
public URL createHTML(ReportValidationTO validationTO) throws IOException, SAXException, IntrospectionException {
    try {
        PATH_XML = File.createTempFile("validacion", ".xml").getAbsolutePath();
        String path_xsl = ConfigurationParametersManager.getParameter(PATH_XSL);
        BeanReader reader = new BeanReader();
        reader.registerBeanClass("validation", ReportValidationTO.class);
        BeanWriter bWriter = initHTML();
        AttributeDescriptor a1 = new AttributeDescriptor("validationName");
        ElementDescriptor e1 = new ElementDescriptor();
        e1.addAttributeDescriptor(a1);
        XMLBeanInfo xmlInfo = new XMLBeanInfo(ReportValidationTO.class);
        xmlInfo.setElementDescriptor(e1);
        bWriter.write("validationTO", validationTO);
        bWriter.flush();
        InputStream inputXSL = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path_xsl);
        URL retorno = (URL) transformToHTML(PATH_XML, inputXSL);
        return retorno;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("No se pudo cargar el archivo ");
        logger.info("El error fue : " + e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}


private BeanWriter initHTML() throws IOException, MissingConfigurationParameterException {
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(PATH_XML);
        BeanWriter bWriter = new BeanWriter(fWriter);
        bWriter.setIndent("\t");
        String path_xsl = ConfigurationParametersManager.getParameter(PATH_XSL);
        URL url_xsl = getClass().getResource(path_xsl);
        String encoding = "<?xml version=" + "\"1.0\"" + " encoding=" + "\"ISO-8859-1\"" + " standalone=" + "\"yes\"" + "?>";
        String xslFile = "<?xml-stylesheet type=" + "\"text/xsl\"" + " href=" + "\"" + url_xsl + "\"" + "?>";
        bWriter.writeXmlDeclaration(encoding);
        bWriter.writeXmlDeclaration(xslFile);
        return bWriter;
    }
```

And then:

```
private URL transformToHTML(String sXMLData, InputStream inputXSL) {
    try {
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(sXMLData));
        Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
        StringWriter cadenaSalida = new StringWriter();
        Result bufferResultado = new StreamResult(cadenaSalida);
        TransformerFactory factoriaTrans = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformador = factoriaTrans.newTransformer(xsltSource);
        transformador.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        transformador.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        transformador.transform(xmlSource, bufferResultado);
        File salida = File.createTempFile("validacion", ".html");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(salida);
        byte[] bytesSalida = cadenaSalida.toString().getBytes();
        out.write(bytesSalida);
        out.close();
        URL url = salida.toURI().toURL();
        return url;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("\nERROR EN TRANSFORM HTML VALIDACIONES");
        logger.error(LoggerHelper.getStackTrace(e));
        return null;
    }
}
```

------- Update with some HTML code -------

```html
<a href="#Linked Example"><font face="Verdana" color="#003399"><b>Title Example</b></font></a>
<ul type="disc">
<li>
<a href="#Link 1: Frase con acentos, est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n"><font size="-1" face="Verdana">SERIALNUMER2: Frase con acentos, el estado est&aacute; en ejecuci&oacute;n</font></a><a><font size="-1" color="red" face="Verdana">
                [Fails:
                3
                ]
               </font></a>
</li>
</ul>

<a name="Linked Example"></a><b><font size="+1" face="Verdana">After click on the second link from above, it should send you here</font></b>
<hr color="black" WIDTH="100%">
<br>
<a name="Link 1: Frase con acentos, el estado est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n"></a><b><font size="-1" face="Verdana">Validacion:</font></b><font size="-1" face="Verdana">SERIALNUMER2: Frase con acentos, el estado est&aacute; en ejecuci&oacute;n</font>
<br>
<b><font size="-1" face="Verdana">Solution:</font></b><font size="-1" face="Verdana">None</font>
<br>
<br>
<table WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1">
<caption>
<font size="+1" face="Verdana" color="red">Error list</font>
</caption>
<tr>
<th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column1</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column2</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column3</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column4</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column5</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column6</b></th><th align="LEFT" bgcolor="dddddd"><b>column7</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT">2000</td><td align="LEFT">15</td><td align="LEFT">019</td><td align="LEFT">001</td><td align="LEFT">1087</td><td align="LEFT">0</td><td align="LEFT">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT">2000</td><td align="LEFT">15</td><td align="LEFT">019</td><td align="LEFT">001</td><td align="LEFT">1113</td><td align="LEFT">0</td><td align="LEFT">B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT">2000</td><td align="LEFT">15</td><td align="LEFT">069</td><td align="LEFT">001</td><td align="LEFT">125</td><td align="LEFT">0</td><td align="LEFT">B</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<b><font size="-1" color="#FF0000" face="Verdana">
           Total:
           3
           fail(s)
          </font></b>
<br>
<b><font size="-1" face="Verdana">
           The end
           :
          </font></b><b><font color="red" size="-1" face="Verdana">Problems found</font></b>
```

On the snippet, here:

```
href="#Link 1: Frase con acentos, est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n"
```

and here:

```
name="Link 1: Frase con acentos, el estado est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n"
```

To make it work on Edge, I need replace *%C3%A1* with *a* and *%C3%B3* with *o* if you want to get redirected to the position on the page where are the details of the link.

Comment: Well, you seem to do the XSLT transformation on the server, using Java, so it doesn't seem to be related to XSLT but rather to making sure your HTML content sent to the browser has consistent and meaningful declarations of the encoding. As for `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "text/html");`, that is nonsense, the method names are `html` or `xml` or `text` (or `xhtml` with XSLT 2.0). What we really need to know is whether you send the HTML over HTTP to the browser and how your HTTP headers look in that case or whether you load the HTML result as a local file in those browsers.

Comment: We also need to see your Java code creating the HTML result so post that as well as the two lines you have shown do not tell us at all whether the settings you attempt in those lines or try to embody literally in the HTML make any sense with the way you write the result.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've updated the info.

Comment: Using `new FileWriter(PATH_XML)` and then doing `"<?xml version=" + "\"1.0\"" + " encoding=" + "\"ISO-8859-1\"" + " standalone=" + "\"yes\"" + "?>";` is also asking for trouble, don't try to put an XML declaration with encoding attribute into some XML document by using string operations and not XML aware, default encoding restricted FileWriter APIs.

Comment: Hi Martin, if I remove this XML declaration althought I specify <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/> on the XSLT, I get this error: **javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.**

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve in that method `initHTML`, and I can't tell how it relates to `transformToHTML` as it doesn't seem to be used in there. I am afraid so far we only seen snippets trying to set or manipulate the encoding but I am not sure how they belong together. The input encoding of XML input or stylesheet certainly has nothing to do with the output encoding and so far your question is about characters in the output not being rendered as desired. Where are the accented characters you want to have in the output coming from, from the XML input, the XSLT code, or both?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot add one function, now you can see when initHTML it's called. But I think I've found the problem. The phrases where are the accented words are retreived from a BD and on some of them there is a final space at the end. It seems that Firefox "trim" de URL (or ignores the spaces after the last character) but Chrome no, so after remove the final space on the phrases affected now the links work on Chrome. On Internet Explorer and Edge still not working.

Comment: On Edge works if the unicode characters are removed and replaced with normal characters, e.g: %C3%BA (ú) by u. I don't know why Edge don't like unicode characters.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing others to reproduce the problem, if the problem is about Edge and links with some accented characters then you can even present that to us in an executable HTML snippet you embed in the question, it certainly doesn't depend on your Java code executed in a desktop to create some HTML file rendered by Edge.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have added a snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does the second link in that HTML snippet scroll to the linked item in Firefox or Chrome? For me it does not.

Comment: Maybe beacuse there is too small the example, but on the original sheet there are a lot of items to show and it works.

Comment: Spaces in fragment identifiers of URLs are not allowed at all in HTML or in general in URLs so I don't think you should expect e.g. `<a href="#name with space">link</a>` to work, run it through validator.w3.org and it will complain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I dind't care of that because Firefox accepted it :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the links work. Thanks to **Rob Parsons** and **Martin Honnen**

The problems where these two:

1. The URL at **href** was being generated with spaces (thanks Martin)

`href="#Link 1: Frase con acentos, est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n" <- I removed the spaces on the XSLT with translate(validationName, ' ','-')`

2. On the reference of the **href** link as these was a legacy code, there was **name** but in HTML5 it's deprecated so now you must use "id" so here:

I changed:

```
**name**="Link 1: Frase con acentos, el estado est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n" (also removed spaces with translate(validationName, ' ','-'))
```

by

```
**id**="Link 1: Frase con acentos, el estado est%C3%A1 en ejecuci%C3%B3n" (also removed spaces with translate(validationName, ' ','-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

So what is the aim, writing out a HTML file with the Java `Transformer`? In which encoding? And if you want to write out a file why are you using a StringWriter in between? Consider to declare in the XSLT with e.g. `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>` which output method and encoding you want, then, to write with your Transformer to the HTML file named `validacion.html` simply create a `new StreamResult("validacion.html")` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult-java.lang.String-)and pass that to the `transform` method. And don't put any encoding info (like `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` literally into the HTML your XSLT creates, the `Transformer` will do its job based on the `xsl:output` directive, as long as you let it do its job with properly used `StreamResult`. Trying to create a temporary StringWriter result and converting a string to bytes to write them out to a FileOutputStream is not necessary and probably causing encoding/decoding inconsistency.

Comment: Ok, thanks Martin. I'm going to try your suggestions. It's a legacy code, so I don't know why the other person did this on that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<font>
```

is depreciated. Use css font-family instead. Web browsers have a default font-family that they will fall back to if any of the css font-families are not installed on the OS. IE has an accessibility setting to "Ignore font styles specified on web pages".
Wikipedia uses this style rule.

```
.uc {
        font-family: Code2000, "TITUS Cyberbit Basic", "Doulos SIL",
            "Chrysanthi Unicode", "Bitstream Cyberbit",
            "Bitstream CyberBase", Thryomanes, Gentium, GentiumAlt,
            "Lucida Grande", "Arial Unicode MS", "Microsoft Sans Serif",
            "Lucida Sans Unicode";
        font-family /**/:inherit; /* resets fonts for everyone but IE6 */
}
```

add the uc class to the body tag.

To debug your web page output use the DOM Explorer of the dev tool, to inspect the css rules applied to the element or textContent of an element.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Rob.